# How many clams do splatted players drop in Clam Blitz?

Tags: splatoon-3

When a player gets splatted in Clam Blitz, what determines the amount of clams that get dropped for other players to pick up?

From my experience players only seem to only drop 3 clams at most, but I can't tell if the dropped clams are a fraction of the clams the player was holding or just a hard cap. For example, if a player was splatted while carrying 3 clams, would all 3 clams be dropped for another player to pick up?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of playing Clam Blitz, the number of clams dropped varies on how many clams the play splatted collected. I have seen players drop more than 3 clams.

Answer (score 0):

A player will drop up to 3 clams when splatted. When a player has clams and picks up a Power Clam, they will drop all of their clams.